# Having Trouble Executing While Loop

Tags: python, excel, while-loop

I am attempting to create a coronavirus temp scan compare program. I want to open an excel file and create a small database each day of scanned employees. When I execute I am just getting the first input prompt and my excel spreadsheet is not opening. My goal was to have each line of code under the while statement nested and would continue to loop until the program operator ended the loop. My code is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
from datetime import date
from xlwt import Workbook

# Workbook is created
wb = Workbook()

# add sheet
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Temperature Scans')

sheet1.write(0, 0, 'First Name')
sheet1.write(0, 1, 'Last Name')
sheet1.write(0, 2, 'Date')
sheet1.write(0, 3, 'Temperature')

Normal = 98.6

Recording = input("Are you Recording Temperature Today? 1 if yes; 0 if no: ")

while Recording == 1:
    Employee_First = input("Enter First Name: ")
    Employee_Last = input("Enter Last Name: ")
    Temp = float(input("Input Scanned Temperature (Example if 99 degrees enter 99): "))
    if Temp > Normal:
            print("Elevated Temperature Detected! Entrance Not Permitted")
    else:
            print("Temperature Within Acceptable Limits. Entrance Permitted")
    Date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
    for i in range(0, 15000):
            sheet1.write(i+1, 0, Employee_First)
            sheet1.write(i+1, 1, Employee_Last)
            sheet1.write(i+1, 2, Date)
            sheet1.write(i+1, 3, Temp)

            Day = today.strftime("%d")
            Month = today.strftime("%m")
            Year = today.strftime("%y")

            wb.save(Month, _ , Day, _ , Year, 'Temp Scans.xlsx')

    break

    continue
```

Comment: `Recording == 1`— This is never true because `Recording` is a string, not an int.

Comment: Unrelated, but you might experience better performance if you use pandas dataframes and occasionally save to a csv file, rather than writing every cell separately in Excel

Comment: @khelwood I adjusted the recording variable to accept input as a float and now the while loop is executing. Are you able to open an excel spreadsheet through the IDLE environment

Comment: @ bug_spray pandas may be more suited for me. I just ran with one of the first imported modules I found. Is that why I can't seem to open a workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Change this of your code:

```
Recording = input("Are you Recording Temperature Today? 1 if yes; 0 if no: ")
```

To:

```
try:
    Recording = int(input("Are you Recording Temperature Today? 1 if yes; 0 if no: "))
except:
    print("Please enter a valid number (either 1 or 0)")
```

in order to make sure that you enter the `while` loop:

```
...
while Recording == 1:
    Employee_First = input("Enter First Name: ")
...
```

Since the [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) will always return a string variable and you are making the comparison on the while loop with an integer.

**EDIT**

Here is a mofification of the code you provided using the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library. The code below will interactively ask for the employee's first name, last name and temperature and finally overwrite the `temperaturescans.xlsx` file (or create it if it doesn't exist and you run the python script for the first time).

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime

#Create workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Fill up the headers on the first row
ws['A1'] = 'First Name'
ws['B1'] = 'Last Name'
ws['C1'] = 'Date'
ws['D1'] = 'Temperature'

#Define some constant values
normal_temperature = 98.6
date = datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%y')

try:
    recording = int(input("Are you Recording Temperature Today? 1 if yes; 0 if no: "))
except:
     print('Please enter a number: either 1 or 0')

while recording == 1:
    #Get employees First Name
    employee_first = input('Enter First Name:')
    #Get employees Last Name
    employee_last = input('Enter Last Name:')
    #Get temperature
    try:
        temperature = float(input('Input Scanned Temperature (example if 99 degrees enter 99):'))
    except:
        print('Please enter a valid value for the temperature (99.2, 98.6)')
    #Check if the employee has a fever
    if temperature > normal_temperature:
        print('Elevated Temperature Detected! Entrance Not Permitted')
    else:
        print("Temperature Within Acceptable Limits. Entrance Permitted")
    #Add the employees row to the sheet
    ws.append([employee_first,employee_last,date,temperature])

    try:
        recording = int(input("Are you Recording Temperature Today? 1 if yes; 0 if no: "))
    except:
        print('All recordings have been made. Saving the file.')

#Save the file
print('Check the temperaturescans.xlsx file for the results.')
wb.save("temperaturescans.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for this information I am now able to execute the while loop. Do you know when executing code in IDLE if it will open an excel spreadsheet if coded correctly?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the [xlwt](https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/) dependency. Nonethess take into consideration that the last [release was as of 2017](https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/#history) and [their developers suggest to use another dependency](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-excel/P6TjJgFVjMI/g8d0eWxTBQAJ): [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: I edited my answer to add an working example of how to create a new .xlsx file where you interactively add the employee's first name, last name, and temperature using the `openpyxl` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The input statement will only take input as a string, it is up to you to convert it into different formats:

```
Recording = input("Are you Recording Temperature Today? 1 if yes; 0 if no: ")

while Recording == '1':
    # do something
```